# Openssl - how to simulate a server that accepts a cipher

Tags: openssl, pki

How can I simulate an OpenSSL server that supports the cipher `RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256`

```
openssl s_server -key key.pem -cert cert.pem -cipher RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256 -accept 44330 -www
```

when I run this I get the following error.

```
Error with command: "-cipher RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA256"
```

`openssl ciphers -v` does not contain the above cipher as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That ciphersuite name is the standard RFC name for it. OpenSSL (for historical reasons) uses its own names for ciphersuites. The mapping is on this page:

https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man1/ciphers.html

The OpenSSL name for that particular ciphersuite is "AES128-SHA256".